# How to load R's .rdata files into Python?

Tags: python, pandas, rpy2

I am trying to convert one part of R code in to Python. In this process I am facing some problems.

I have a R code as shown below. Here I am saving my R output in **.rdata** format.

```
nms <- names(mtcars)
save(nms,file="mtcars_nms.rdata")
```

Now I have to load the mtcars_nms.rdata into Python.
I imported rpy2 module. Then I tried to load the file into python workspace. But could not able to see the actual output.

I used the following python code to import the **.rdata**.

```
import pandas as pd
from rpy2.robjects import r,pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()

robj = r.load('mtcars_nms.rdata')
robj
```

My python output is

```
R object with classes: ('character',) mapped to:
<StrVector - Python:0x000001A5B9E5A288 / R:0x000001A5B9E91678>
['mtcars_nms']
```

Now my objective is to extract the information from mtcars_nms.

In R, we can do this by using

```
load("mtcars_nms.rdata");
get('mtcars_nms')
```

Now I wanted to do the same thing in Python.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a new python package [pyreadr](https://github.com/ofajardo/pyreadr) that makes very easy import RData and Rds files into python:

```
import pyreadr

result = pyreadr.read_r('mtcars_nms.rdata')

mtcars = result['mtcars_nms']
```

It does not depend on having R or other external dependencies installed.
It is a wrapper around the C library [librdata](https://github.com/WizardMac/librdata), therefore it is very fast.

You can install it very easily with pip:

```
pip install pyreadr
```

The repo is here: https://github.com/ofajardo/pyreadr

Disclaimer: I am the developer.

Comment: Hi, when i try to load .rdata of the size 700M, such error occurs:ValueError: Unable to allocate memory

Comment: hi, thanks for trying the package! a 700 M RData file is huge! Do you have enough RAM? Take into account that RData is highly compressed. For example, I have a 40 M RData file, if I save it as CSV it takes 450 M so 11 times more. If you load that into R it occupies 1.3 Gb! and loading into python takes 1.8 Gb! meaning 45 times more (pandas is very hungry). That means if you have a 700 Mb RData file, you need at least 32 Gb of RAM! and that would be very tight, because the process needs transiently even more RAM. I would say you would need at least 64 GB RAM or so.

Comment: In the librdata C library there is a hard coded limit for max number of bytes a vector in a data frame can have. It used to be 2**24 bytes, meaning 2**22 integers or 2**21 doubles, which is relatively low. If a vector contains more bytes than this a memory error was raised. It has been increased in the newest version to 2**32 bytes, meaning 2**30 intengers or 2**29 doubles, which should be enough for practical purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using the `.rdata` format, I would recommend to use [feather](https://github.com/wesm/feather), which allows to efficiently share data between R and Python.

In R, you would run something like this:

```
library(feather)
write_feather(nms, "mtcars_nms.feather")
```

In Python, to load the data into a `pandas` dataframe, you can then simply run:

```
import pandas as pd
nms = pd.read_feather("mtcars_nms.feather")
```

Answer (score 0):

The R function `load` will return an R vector of names for the objects that were loaded (into GlobalEnv).

You'll have to do in rpy2 pretty much what you are doing in R:

R:

```
get('mtcars_nms')
```

Python/rpy2

```
robjects.globalenv['mtcars_nms']
```